# How to display $request values inside the controller

Tags: laravel

Inside the `Store` method How I can print the `$request` variable values ? I tried like that

```
var_dump($request);
or echo $request;
```

But nothing was displayed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are in a controller and $request is of type Request, then you can do:

```
\Log::info($request->all());
```

Comment: little new. how I can view the log ?

Comment: @Wel, the log is on the `storage/logs` folder, named `larave.log` by default.

Comment: log is in /app/storage/laravel.log (if your logging is default and you don't have some custom setup).

Answer (score 2):

Try this I always use:

```
dd($request->toArray())
```